# Payment gateway redirect not sending request parameters to URL in production mode

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am working on a payment plugin for woocommerce, in test mode it works correctly. But in real mode it doesn't work for me.

My function to make the payment is:

```
  public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Get this Order's information so that we know
    // who to charge and how much
    $customer_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $environment_url = 'https://credomatic.compassmerchantsolutions.com/api/transact.php';

    $time = time();
    $key_id = $this->key_id;
    $orderid = str_replace( "#", "", $customer_order->get_order_number() );
    $hash = md5($orderid."|".$customer_order->order_total."|".$time."|".$this->api_key);
    // This is where the fun stuff begins
    $payload = array(
      "key_id"  => $key_id,
      "hash" => $hash,
      "time" => $time,
      "amount" => $customer_order->order_total,
      "ccnumber" => str_replace( array(' ', '-' ), '', $_POST['bac_payment-card-number'] ),
      "ccexp" => str_replace( array( '/', ' '), '', $_POST['bac_payment-card-expiry'] ),
      "orderid" => $orderid,
      "cvv" => ( isset( $_POST['bac_payment-card-cvc'] ) ) ? $_POST['bac_payment-card-cvc'] : '',
      "type" => "auth",
      "redirect" => "https://testsite.com/paymentvalidator.php"
     );
    // Send this payload to Authorize.net for processing
    $response = wp_remote_post( $environment_url, array(
      'method'    => 'POST',
      'body'      => http_build_query( $payload ),
      'timeout'   => 90,
      'sslverify' => false,
    ) );
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) 
      throw new Exception( __( 'We are currently experiencing problems trying to connect to this payment gateway. Sorry for the inconvenience.'.$payload, 'bac-payment' ) );
    if ( empty( $response['body'] ) )
      throw new Exception( __( 'BAC\'s Response was empty.', 'bac-payment' ) );

    // Retrieve the body's resopnse if no errors found
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
```

In test mode `$response` -> returns:

```
    Array
    (
        [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
            (
                [data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => Wed, 11 Dec 2019 20:31:13 GMT
                        [server] => Apache
                        [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.6.40
                        [strict-transport-security] => max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                        [content-length] => 293
                        [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                    )

            )

        [body] => https://testsite.com/paymentvalidator.php?response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=5062787706&avsresponse=&cvvresponse=N&orderid=9142&type=sale&response_code=100&username=13783068&time=1576096273&amount=11.00&hash=a5d8276d11041ead7ec3f390d1df6707
        [response] => Array
            (
                [code] => 200
                [message] => OK
            )
    .
    .
    .

                    [status_code] => 200
                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                    [success] => 1
                    [redirects] => 1
                    [url] => https://testsite.com/paymentvalidator.php?response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=5062787706&avsresponse=&cvvresponse=N&orderid=9142&type=sale&response_code=100&username=13783068&time=1576096273&amount=11.00&hash=a5d8276d11041ead7ec3f390d1df6707
                    [history] => Array
.
.
.
```

But in production mode `$response` -> returns:

```
    Array
    (
        [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
            (
                [data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => Fri, 13 Dec 2019 16:38:02 GMT
                        [server] => Apache
                        [x-gw-session-id] => 8d4bbf45eabe4a5edac4aeba06cb8753
                        [content-length] => 1175
                        [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                    )

            )

        [body] => <HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT Language="Javascript">function onLoadHandler(){document.frmLaunchACS.submit();}</SCRIPT></HEAD><body onLoad="onLoadHandler();"><br><br><br><br><center><FORM name="frmLaunchACS" method="Post" action="https://0eaf.cardinalcommerce.com/EAFService/jsp/v1/redirect"><input type=hidden name="PaReq" value="P.02c473b41ce5b88887fc8936601d76171ef6ef34e10d1f0472e21e0c4a725c3d10b4d051fb***"><input type=hidden name="TermUrl" value="https://credomatic.compassmerchantsolutions.com/api/transact.php?username=user11&amp;APISID=8d4bbf45eabe4a5edac8753&amp;centinel_transaction_id=mURX2oj4BDd977pRFP30&amp;cardholder_auth_key=745701d7f2f1b3ffedddc72d16c1x"><input type=hidden name="MD" value="none"><noscript>     <br><br>     <center>     <font color="red">     <h1>Processing your Payer Authentication Transaction</h1>     <h2>JavaScript is currently disabled or is not supported by your browser.<br></h2>     <h3>Please click Submit to continue    the processing of your transaction.</h3>     </font>     <input type="submit" value="Submit">     </center> </noscript> </FORM></center></BODY></HTML>
        [response] => Array
            (
                [code] => 200
                [message] => OK
            )
    .
    .
    .
[status_code] => 200
                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                    [success] => 1
                    [redirects] => 0
                    [url] => https://credomatic.compassmerchantsolutions.com/api/transact.php
                    [history] => Array
.
.
.
```

As you can see in production does not return the body with the URL and parameters of the bank, which in test mode if it returns the response parameters correctly.

Another detail is that in test mode returns `[redirects] => 1` and production mode returns:`[redirects] => 0`

It seems that the parameter: `"redirect" => "http://testsite.com/paymentvalidator.php"`  does not run in production mode.

I have also tested the payment in a simple html form and everything works correctly in test and production mode, so I rule out that it is a bank problem.

**Any suggestions of what the mistake would be?**

In postman:
[image: response in postman]